# Need help for an array or matrix

Tags: matrices, arrays, nicematrix

I am trying to make an array or matrix to represent this matrix:
[image]

But unfortunately, I don't manage to do it (I even don't know if I should do it with an array or a pmatrix).
So, if someone can help me...

Comment: Just a clue, `nicematrix` have good features to achieve this...Please post the content your image in `TeX` format, as no one wants to `keyin` the content....

Comment: Thank you. I will look at nicematrix. Sorry, but I didn’t understand the problem about my image. It is in jpeg, so how do I post in TeX?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is a fairly faithful reproduction of the matrix using the `nicematrix` package.

The solid lines were drawn using the package's ability to insert tikz  commands (with `\CodeAfter`) between the nodes it creates in the cells.

Requires compiling twice.

[image: b]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}   

\usepackage{tikz} % needed <<<<<<<  
\usepackage{nicematrix} %    needed <<<<<<<

\begin{document}
    \setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}
\[\tilde{A'} = \begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-row, cell-space-limits=5pt]
    &   &   &j_{1}  &   &       &   &j_{2}  &   &\cdots &       &j_{r-1}&       &\cdots &   &j_{r}  &   &       &   &\\
0   &-  &0  &1      &*  &\Cdots &*  &0      &*  &\Cdots &*      &0      &*      &\Cdots &*          &0      &*      &\Cdots &*      &b'_{1} \\
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &\Vdots &\Vdots &\Vdots &       &\Vdots     &\Vdots &\Vdots &       &\Vdots &       \\[-10pt]
    &   &0  &       &   &       &0  &1      &*  &       &       &       &       &       &           &       &       &       &       &b'_{2} \\
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &           &       &       &       &       &       \\[-10pt]
    &   &   &       &   &       &0  &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &           &       &       &       &       &b'_{3} \\
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &*      &0      &       &       &           &       &       &       &       &\Vdots \\
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &0      &1      &*      &\Cdots &*          &0      &       &       &       &b'_{r-1}\\
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &           &       &       &       &       &       \\[-10pt]       
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &0      &       &       &       &0          &1      &*      &\Cdots &*      &b'_{r} \\
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &           &       &       &       &       &       \\[-10pt]
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &0          &       &       &       &0      &b'_{r+1}\\
    &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &           &       &       &       &       &\Vdots \\
0   &   &   &       &   &       &   &       &   &       &       &       &       &       &           &       &       &       &0      &b'_{n} \\
\CodeAfter 
\tikz \draw  (2-|1.5) -- (13-|1.5); 
\tikz \draw  (3-|4) -- (3-|7); 
\tikz \draw  (5-|8) -- (5-|9); 
\tikz \draw  (7.5-|10) -- (7.5-|11); 
\tikz \draw  (9-|12) -- (9-|15); 
\tikz \draw  (11-|16) -- (11-|19); 
\tikz \draw  (13.5-|2) -- (13.5-|19); 
\tikz \draw  (2-|3.5) -- (2.5-|3.5); 
\tikz \draw  (4-|7.5) -- (4.5-|7.5); 
\tikz \draw  (8-|11.5) -- (8.5-|11.5); 
\tikz \draw  (10-|15.5) -- (10.5-|15.5); 
\tikz \draw  (12-|19.5) -- (13-|19.5); 
\end{pNiceMatrix}\]

\end{document}
```

Comment: Waouh! Thank you very much, Simon. I really need to look at nicematrix

Comment: I looked at nicematrix and I understand most of your code. But I don’t understand the horizontal lines. For instance, the line \tikz \draw  (3-|4) -- (3-|7). Why isn’t it \tikz \draw  (3.5-|4) -- (3.5-|7); like in the last horizontal line?

Comment: @Didier  Very good! You pinpointed a small anomaly. The second line (with the `\Vdot`s) ended up taller than the   the others blank lines so the third line is in a lower position.

For the same reason, the second vertical line --one row high--, is longer than the next three. The improvement is left to the reader :-)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will look at this closely

Comment: In fact, the negative values of the command `\\` (eg `\\[-10pt]`) are not compatible with `nicematrix` and that's why there is a problem with the position of the Tikz nodes...

Comment: @F. Pantigny  It is `\\[-10tpt]`    used to raise the empty row, not `\[10pt]`

Answer (score 3):

Here is another solution with `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\setcounter{MaxMatrixCols}{20}

\[
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.4}
\widetilde{A'}=
\begin{pNiceMatrix}[nullify-dots,first-row]
 & &j_1& &      & &j_2& &\cdots       &      &j_{r-1}&      &\cdots&      &j_r   &      &      &      &\\ 
0&0&1  &*&\Cdots&*&0  &*&\hspace*{1cm}& *    &0     &*     &\Cdots&*     &0     &*     &\Cdots&*     &b_1' \\
 &0&   & &      &0&1  &*&             &\Vdots&\Vdots&\Vdots&      &\Vdots&\Vdots&\Vdots&      &\Vdots&b_2' \\
 & &   & &      &0&   & &             &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &b_3' \\
 & &   & &      & &   & &             &*     &0     &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &\Vdots \\
 & &   & &      & &   & &             &0     &1     &*     &\Cdots&*     &0     &      &      &      &b_{r-1}' \\
 & &   & &      & &   & &             &0     &      &      &      &0     &1     &*     &\Cdots&*     &b_r' \\
 & &   & &      & &   & &             &      &      &      &      &0     &      &      &      &0     &b_{r+1}' \\
 & &   & &      & &   & &             &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &\Vdots \\  
0& &   & &      & &   & &             &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &      &0     &b_n' 
\CodeAfter
  \begin{tikzpicture} [shorten < = 1mm, shorten > = 1mm]
  \draw (3-6) -- ++(1cm,0) ;
  \draw (2-6) -- (3-6) ;
  \draw (2-2) -- (2-6) ;
  \draw (1-2) -- (2-2) ;
  \draw (1-1) -- (1-2) ;
  \draw (1-1) -- (last-1) ;
  \draw (last-1) -- (last-18) ;
  \draw (last-18) -- (7-18) ;
  \draw (7-18) -- (7-14) ;
  \draw (7-14) -- (6-14) ;
  \draw (6-14) -- (6-10) ; 
  \draw (6-10) -- (5-10) ;
  \draw (5-10) -- ++(-1cm,0) ; 
  %
  \draw [dashed] (1-8) -- (1-10) ;
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceMatrix}
\]

\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

[image: Output of the above code]